# sass - when to use and when not

Tags: css, sass

so its not exactly a "code question". its more about the approach to using it.

I got this design psds and they said I gotta use sass.
I am quite familiar with sass for some time, and I structured it properly into folders, vars whatever...

my question is how far do I need to go with that? Do I need to store **eveything** in variables, mixins and so on, or if I just wanna get it out in plain css cause its faster for my brain to process the idea that I had and latter refactor it into sass. cause that beats the whole purpose of it.

for example I got this icon divs

```
.icons-bar .icon-item .icon-wrap {
    width:100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin:auto;        
}
```

which I can use easy like

```
.icons-bar .icon-item .icon-wrap:nth-child(1) {
    background: url('../img/icons/icons-camera.png') no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;               
} 

.icons-bar .icon-item .icon-wrap:nth-child(2) {
    background: url('../img/icons/icons-doctor.png') no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;               
}
```

versus writing a mixin for it and including it

```
@mixin icon-make($icon) {
   width:100%;
   height: 50px;
   margin:auto; 
   background: url('../img/icons/icons-' + $icon) no-repeat;
   background-position: 50%;

}
```

Just a simple example, in this case I say its more efficient to write plain css with pseudos versus wasting time making a mixin. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start with Sass because it will help with the organization of your css once your website goes to production. If another developer comes in after you and tries to work on your Sass files(that are structures into variables, mixins, parts of the site, etc), then it will be easier them him/her to modify the sass files rather then go into a big css file and try to find where everything is.

Answer (score 0):

If i got it right, you are talking about OOCSS (first sample) vs Smacss/ Bem.

Bem modifier could be a better choice (with specific class name )for maintaining 
it would be

```
<span class="footer__icon footer__icon--camera"></span>
<span class="footer__icon footer__icon--doctor"></span>
```

Self documented code. when you read the html you can get the idea of how sass organised

About variables, NO, you don't need to save all of them